# How to place a string inside another string , instead of the character at some index

Tags: c++, string, insert

If I have :  `Enter(x)`

And I want to place after the `(` the word `room2` , but without `x` , then std::insert doesn't help 
since if :

```
std::string myString = "Enter(x)";
std::string placeMe = "room2";
myString.insert(myString.find_first_of("(") + 1 , placeMe);
```

Then I'd get : `Enter(room2x)` .

How can I place the `placeMe` **instead** of a certain index ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is replace instead of insert.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Answer (score 3):

First, you probably want `find` instead of `find_first_of`, since you only want to match one possible substring. Second, you want the `std::string::replace` function:

```
myString.replace(myString.find("(") + 1, 1, placeMe);
```